# input[type="submit"] disable если поля формы не валидны

Tags: jquery

Использую плагин валидации [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) формы.

Есть такая простая форма:

```js
(function() {

  var app = {

    init: function() {
      this.setUpListeners();
    },

    setUpListeners: function() {

      $(document).on('submit', 'form', this.submitForm);
      $(document).on('keyup', 'input', this.removeError);
    },

    submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      var form = $(this),
          btnSubmit = form.find('[type="submit"]');

      if (form.validate().form() === false) {
        
      
        btnSubmit.addClass('disabled');
        
        return false;
      }    

      
    },
    
    removeError: function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          formGroup = $this.closest('.form-group'),
          form = $(this).closest('form'),
          btnSubmit = form.find('[type="submit"]');

      btnSubmit.removeClass('disabled');  
    }

    
  }

  app.init();
})();
```

```css
label.error {
  color:red;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.disabled {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  
<form class="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name-1" class="form-control" data-rule-required="true" data-msg="Ошибка при заполнении" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="phone-1" class="form-control js-phone" data-rule-required="true" data-msg="Ошибка при заполнении" placeholder="Телефон">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="agree-1"  data-rule-required="true" name="agree">
      
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="agree-1">
        Заполняя форму, вы соглашаетесь со всем!
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Заказать" class="btn btn-success">
  
</form>
```

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать добавление\удаления класса `disable` для `[type="submit"]` при валидных\невалидных полях формы? Сейчас класс добавляется, если поля не валидны, но не исчезает если все заполнить и чекнуть.

Comment: где `this.removeError`?

Comment: @Grundy, обновила, добавила `removeError:`

Comment: @Grundy, но так `disable` исчезает в любом случае, просто если начинаешь что-то вводить, а должно исчезать только если все введено, отмечено и правильно\валидно

Comment: а у меня исчезает, если хотя бы одно поле заполнить

Comment: @Grundy, аха, а должно исчезать, только если  все правильно заполнены и появляться обратно если удалить текст в этом поле или убрать чекбокс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению данный плагин не предоставляет никаких событий на то, что валидация прошла или нет.

Однако можно обрабатывать события проверки конкретных элементов [onfocusout](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout), [onkeyup](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup), [onclick](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onclick) и в них уже проверять валидность формы и выставлять класс кнопке.

Пример.

```js
(function() {

  var app = {

    init: function() {
      var form = $('.form');
      var btnSubmit = form.find('[type=submit]');
      form.validate({
        onkeyup: function(...args) {
          btnSubmit.toggleClass('disabled', !this.form());
        },
        onclick: function(...args) {
          btnSubmit.toggleClass('disabled', !this.form());
        },
        onfocusout: function(...args) {
          btnSubmit.toggleClass('disabled', !this.form());
        },
        invalidHandler: function(...args) {
          btnSubmit.addClass('disabled');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form, e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('success');
        }
      });
    }



  }

  app.init();
})();
```

```css
label.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.disabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name-1" class="form-control" data-rule-required="true" data-msg="Ошибка при заполнении" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="phone-1" class="form-control js-phone" data-rule-required="true" data-msg="Ошибка при заполнении" placeholder="Телефон">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="agree-1" data-rule-required="true" name="agree">

      <label class="custom-control-label" for="agree-1">
        Заполняя форму, вы соглашаетесь со всем!
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Заказать" class="btn btn-success">

</form>
```

Возможно, что-то можно сделать с помощью каких-нибудь `rules` добавленных для самой кнопки, но до конца этот путь пройти не удалось.

Comment:  

Comment: @HamSter, обрати внимание, что код настройки плагина чуть поменялся, по сравненнию с твоим :-)

Comment: Я вижу, но времени нет проверить в своем проекте, поэтому позже буду еще смотреть! Тут работает все отлично)

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что тут `$.ajax({
                    url: 'contacts.php',` ajax обработку в `submitHandler: function(form, e) { ...` нужно вставить?

Comment: вот такая куча-мала https://jsbin.com/pakuger/edit?html,js,output получилась и работает, но .... явно что-то не так)))))

Comment: @HamSter, если работает - все так :)

Comment: вот это ` if (msg === "OK") {

          setTimeout(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
          }, 1000); ` видимо не работает, окно удачной отправки не закрывается, да и вообще все окна

Comment: попробовала у себя на хостинге, не работает обработка contacts.php ajax запрос ... письмо не отправляется, ошибок нет

Comment: @HamSter, Ну так не бывает :-)

Comment: ну вот как-то так, не работает!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971279/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83